# Microsoft rxNeuralNet acceleration

Tags: r, microsoft-r

In Microsoft's R NeuralNet package, there is an option for acceleration, where you can specify "GPU" or "SSE". I know what GPU is, does anyone know what SSE acceleration is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSE stands for "Streaming SIMD Extensions".  SIMD stands for "Single Instruction Multiple Data".

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005779.html

David

Comment: Oh. Okay, thanks! This is not anywhere in MS's documentation, at least none that I could find. Does this methodology actually make neural network training faster?

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but my understanding is that SSE is faster than using ordinary CPU instructions, but not as fast as using a GPU.

Comment: Hi. Okay, that's what I thought as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet, so therefore I am posting an "answer".

From what I gather SSE is nowadays "default" unless you have the ability to do GPU. A wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions

Niels